# Sending File Attachment by Mail In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I want to attach a file to the email in Mailer library. As I see in the Mailer description, it says that you can attach files, but I don't see how:

```
final message = Message()
..from = Address(username)
..recipients.add('dest@example.com') //recipent email
..ccRecipients.addAll(['destCc1@example.com', 'destCc2@example.com']) //cc Recipents emails
..bccRecipients.add(Address('bccAddress@example.com')) //bcc Recipents emails
..subject = 'Test Dart Mailer library ::  :: ${DateTime.now()}' //subject of the email
..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.' //body of the email
```

How would I attach a file here (csv file for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this](https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer/blob/master/example/send_gmail.dart)

```
  Iterable<Attachment> toAt(Iterable<String> attachments) =>
      (attachments ?? []).map((a) => FileAttachment(File(a)));

  // Create our message.
  final message = Message()
    ..from = Address('$username@gmail.com', 'My name ')
    ..recipients.addAll(toAd(tos))
    ..ccRecipients.addAll(toAd(args[ccArgs] as Iterable<String>))
    ..bccRecipients.addAll(toAd(args[bccArgs] as Iterable<String>))
    ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.'
    ..html = "<h1>Test</h1>\n<p>Hey! Here's some HTML content</p>"
..attachments.addAll(toAt(args[attachArgs] as Iterable<String>));
```

Comment: I'm getting weird errors, here, any other option, or an example if someone has done it?

Comment: Would you mind to show the error and update  the question? Maybe more detail for your code

Comment: Yep, I'll get on it asap, not at home now, so can't upload it. But I'll see if I can fix it and get back to you asap.

Comment: I solved it with Mailer package, I updated in the main code if anyone has the same issue, just add the `file` in the attachment.